# Rails 4 Nested Resources, Forms, strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, strong-parameters

I am trying to create a workout tracker. I have these nested resources

Routes.rb

```
resources :days do
  resources :workouts
  resources :meals
end
```

My models look fine:

Workout.rb

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :exercises
  belongs_to :day
end
```

Day.rb

```
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts
  has_many :meals
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workouts, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meals, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

The issue lies when I try to create a new workout..

../views/workouts/_form.html.haml

```
= form_for([@day, @workout]), html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
  = f.input :workout, label: "What did you work out", input_html: { class: "form-control"}
  = f.input :mood, label: "How do you feel", input_html: { class: "form-control"}
  = f.hidden_field :day_id, value: params[:day_id], input_html: { class: "form-control"}

  = f.submit
```

I cant seem to save the :day_id the workout is associated with the workout though using strong params to receive them.

WorkoutsController.rb

```
private

def workout_params
  params.require(:workout).permit(:day_id, :name, :mood)
end

def find_day
  @day = Day.find(params[:day_id])
end
```

Instead what gets saved is a nil for :day_id

Rails Console:

```
Workout id: 11, name: "Hey", mood: "no", day_id: nil, created_at: "2014-12-19 14:53:29", updated_at: "2014-12-19 14:53:29"
```

HELP?

PS - i tried to do

```
= form_for([@day, @workout]), as: :foo, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
  = f.input :workout, label: "What did you work out", input_html: { class: "form-control"}
  = f.input :mood, label: "How do you feel", input_html: { class: "form-control"}
  = f.hidden_field :day_id, value: params[:day_id], input_html: { class: "form-control"}

  = f.submit
```

and then

```
def workout_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:day_id, :name, :mood)
end
```

But it just kept saying the :foo params where empty

Comment: Does this work? `Day.find(params[:workout][:day_id])`

Comment: can you run `rake routes` and post the report (or at least the parts that have the day and workout routes)?

Answer (score 0):

The way your routes are set up, I am assuming that the `day_id` is being passed as a url params:

```
/days/:day_id/workouts
```

If that is the case, then you do not need to worry about `@day` in the form, nor the `day_id` in the `workout_params`

Form:

```
= form_for @workout, html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
    = f.input :workout, label: "What did you work out", input_html: { class: "form-control"}
    = f.input :mood, label: "How do you feel", input_html: { class: "form-control"}

    = f.submit
```

Controller:

```
def create
   @workout = @day.workouts.new(workout_params)
   ....
end

private

def workout_params
     params.require(:workout).permit(:name, :mood)
end

def find_day
    @day = Day.find(params[:day_id])
end
```